# Display drop down items based on previous selected value in infopath

Tags: infopath

I am trying to do one thing in sharepoint.

Student should select the **Highest Qualification**. In Highest qualification I am showing 3 values such as:

- Post Graduation,
- Graduation,
- Under Graduation

In another field I want to show all courses for the selected qualification level. How can I achieve this. Do I need to do this in code, or could it all be done in the InfoPath form?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make cascading combobox. You can filter your comboboxes which field u want to.

1.Right click combobox u want to filter

2.Select combobox properties

3.Below datasource list, click the box next to the entries field.

[image]

4.You can filter your comboboxes from here.

Comment: Considering that this process is really tricky, this answer could really use more explanation on HOW to set the filter. This Answer might be helpful : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166947/sharepoint-2013-list-conditional-dropdown-based-on-another-column

Answer (score 0):

In InfoPath 2010 there are Rules, what you can do is make 3 controls for each of the selection and on each control create a Rule to show/hide when the field Highest Selection has certain value... Following link should be helpful

In InfoPath 2007:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146504/how-do-i-conditionally-display-a-field-in-infopath

In InfoPath 2010
http://the-north.com/sharepoint/post/2012/06/12/SharePoint-and-Infopath-2010-Conditionally-Hide-Form-Fields.aspx