# Cascading drop-down with Multi-select field

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, powerapp, multiple-values, cascading

I am not very familiar with editing a SharePoint site but have been tasked with creating a tracking log of sorts.

Currently, I have created two columns in the list for which I would like to relate to each other. One column is a drop-down that only allows you to select one value and the other column is a drop-down as well but allows you to multi-select.

However, I only want to display in the latter, multi-select drop down, certain values depending on the former column value selection.

For example, if you select "HCM" in the first drop-down, I only want to display those related items. If you select "Finance," those respective items in the second drop-down appear but not the ones associated to "HCM".

I see where you can created lookup fields but those appear to be a 1:1 relationship, unless I'm mistaken.

What is the best way to achieve this? Can we accomplish this using PowerApps?

Here's a screenshot of the PowerApps form. The values for "Process Workstream" should only appear depending on what is selected for "Process Level".

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there's no OOTB way to meet your needs.

I recommend you to use InfoPath form.

You can use an xml document to build your data-set for column B with the related value of column A.

In addition ,it can also be achieved with the free SPServices jQuery library by Share Point MVP Marc Anderson.

You can refer to this similar situation below(It also applies to SharePoint online
):

[Sharepoint 2013 List: Conditional dropdown based on another column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166947/sharepoint-2013-list-conditional-dropdown-based-on-another-column)